# How to put a infinite task(Runnable) give up for a while

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

As title, I want to make a Runnable rest for a while, then another task in ExecutorService has the chance to do its task.
Here the assumption:

```
public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        executorService.execute(new Task());
    }
}}

public class Task implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        doTask();
        // how to make this task give up for a while
        // then other tasks in ExecutetorService have
        // change to run like Thread.yield()?
        // Thread.yield();
    }
}

public void doTask() {
    // assume it take some seconds to finish
}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `task` can't give up it's current `Thread`, which was generated by the `ExecutorService`

Comment: Your tasks (Runnable/Callable)  need to implement themselves some logic that can check to pause or resume. There are various ways to do that.

Comment: @akhil_mittal please point out a way sir

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like a Bad Design.  A thread should loop, waiting for just one thing.  When the thing happens, the thread should quickly deal with it, and then go back to waiting for the same thing to happen again.  A _task_ should not wait at all.  Your code should not submit a task to an executor service until the needs of the task have been met.  When the task gets to run, it should promptly do its job and return.  If you think you need to "pause" one task to let another run, then maybe that's a sign that you ought to break the work down into smaller tasks.

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPool will have maximum 5 Threads as per your construction and when you do `Thread.sleep()` or `Thread.yield` (to reduce it's priority but not anything guaranteed), it's making ThreadPool's thread to go sleep not your tasks so pending tasks from Queue won't get chance.

As an alternative option, you can make a queue which will hold half executed Tasks, you put tasks in this queue so you can execute after some time.

Comment: how can I archive that?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment your tasks (Runnable/Callable) need to implement themselves some logic that can check to pause or resume. There are various ways to do that.

Also there is an example `PausableThreadPoolExecutor`in doc itself. The following code is taken from [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) only:

```
class PausableThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
   private boolean isPaused;
   private ReentrantLock pauseLock = new ReentrantLock();
   private Condition unpaused = pauseLock.newCondition();

   public PausableThreadPoolExecutor(...) { super(...); }

   protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
     super.beforeExecute(t, r);
     pauseLock.lock();
     try {
       while (isPaused) unpaused.await();
     } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
       t.interrupt();
     } finally {
       pauseLock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public void pause() {
     pauseLock.lock();
     try {
       isPaused = true;
     } finally {
       pauseLock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public void resume() {
     pauseLock.lock();
     try {
       isPaused = false;
       unpaused.signalAll();
     } finally {
       pauseLock.unlock();
     }
   }
 }
```

The above code makes use of `ReentrantLock` to pause and resume.

Comment: sorry sir, it's out of question, I thought (I have used it actually) PausableThreadPoolExecutor will pause the whole 10 task as I assume, not pause a specific Runnable and give a chance for another Runnable in Executor to run.

Comment: @Vinh.TV: If you want to pause a specific task based on a boolean condition then you can share a volatile among them.